# What is a thread safe way to throw an error while using Rcpp

Tags: multithreading, rcpp

I am using `RcppThread` for parallelism in an `Rcpp` function. What is the preferred way to throw an error in the middle of a parallel loop? R's API is single threaded, so I assume `Rcpp::stop()` is not thread safe. `RcppThread` provides means for thread safe `cout` and `CheckUserInterrupt` but not, so far as I can tell, a thread safe `stop`.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <RcppThread.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppThread)]]

void myfun() {

  // parallel loop
  RcppThread::parallelFor(0, 100, [](int j){
    // do something that causes an error
    Rcpp::stop("Is this error unsafe?");
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not -- The simple and often repeated rule stated eg in the RcppParallel documentation is that *no contact whatsoever* should be made from multithreaded code back into to R, or with R-created/owned memory.

From the top of my head, I would just

- break from the parallel loop
- assign the error condition or text to a string
- once back in single-threaded code call `Rcpp::stop(thattext)`

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Think I'll follow up with the maker of RcppThread for a feature request. :) Thanks, Dirk!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Thomas Nagler from [`RcppThread`'s GitHub](https://github.com/tnagler/RcppThread/issues/39#issuecomment-664441483):

You can use the native C++ `throw std::runtime_error()` and it will be cached until the threads sync back with the main pool. Then the error is pushed to the main thread where it's handled by `Rcpp` as a standard runtime error and pushed to R.

So:

```
#include <RcppThread.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppThread)]]

void myfun() {

  // parallel loop
  RcppThread::parallelFor(0, 100, [](int j){
    // do something that causes an error
    throw std::runtime_error("You did a bad thing");
  });

}
```

Comment: Yes, that is related to what I wrote:  In the parallel sections you can use plain C++ idioms and variables, just not R's.  And `Rcpp::stop()` is a wrapper/extension around plain `try/catch/throw` which helps with formatting -- but you need the unundling to e.g. plain `std::throw`.